# How to get all possible permutations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, permutation, combinatorics

I have a nested list

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', ['g', ['h', 'i']]]]
```

I want to do all possible permutations of elements in sublists without going beyond corresponding sublist.
The expected output are variations of something like this:

```
[['c', 'b', 'a'], ['d'], ['f', 'e', ['g', ['i', 'h']]]]
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'e', [['h', 'i'], 'g']]]
```

Each element must be kept is kept in it's square bracket.

I Worte this generator:

```
def swap(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        res = np.random.choice(x, len(x), replace = False)
        return [list(map(ff, res))]

    else:
        return x
```

It gives random variants of expected result, but i need to collect them all. How could I do it? Should I do:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10000): # not necessary 10000, any huge number
    my_list.append(ff(yy1))
```

And then apply unique function to my_list to select unique ones, or there is another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isinstance()`+`itertools.permutations()` is a good direction, just you need a product of them, and some tracking which permutation applies to what part of the tree(?) (I was thinking along generating all possible traversals of a tree):

```
import itertools

def plan(part,res):
  if isinstance(part,list) and len(part)>1:
    res.append(itertools.permutations(range(len(part))))
    for elem in part:
      plan(elem,res)
  return res

def remix(part,p):
  if isinstance(part,list) and len(part)>1:
    coll=[0]*len(part)
    for i in range(len(part)-1,-1,-1):
      coll[i]=remix(part[i],p)
    mix=p.pop()
    return [coll[i] for i in mix]
  else:
    return part

def swap(t):
  plans=itertools.product(*plan(t,[]))
  for p in plans:
    yield remix(t,list(p))

for r in swap([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', ['g', ['h', 'i']]]]):
  print(r)
```

`plan()` recursively finds all "real" lists (which have more than one element), and creates `itertools.permutations()` for them.

`swap()` calls `plan()`, and then combines the permutations into one single compound megapermutation using `itertools.product()`

`remix()` creates an actual object for a single megapermutation step. It is a bit complicated because I did not want to fight with tracking tree-position, instead `remix()` works backwards, going to the very last list, and swizzling it with the very last component of the current plan, removing it from the list.

It seems to work, though your example is a bit long, with simpler inputs it has manageable output:

> ```
> for r in swap([['a', ['b', 'c']], ['d'], 'e']):
>   print(r)
>
> [['a', ['b', 'c']], ['d'], 'e']
> [['a', ['c', 'b']], ['d'], 'e']
> [[['b', 'c'], 'a'], ['d'], 'e']
> [[['c', 'b'], 'a'], ['d'], 'e']
> [['a', ['b', 'c']], 'e', ['d']]
> [['a', ['c', 'b']], 'e', ['d']]
> [[['b', 'c'], 'a'], 'e', ['d']]
> [[['c', 'b'], 'a'], 'e', ['d']]
> [['d'], ['a', ['b', 'c']], 'e']
> [['d'], ['a', ['c', 'b']], 'e']
> [['d'], [['b', 'c'], 'a'], 'e']
> [['d'], [['c', 'b'], 'a'], 'e']
> [['d'], 'e', ['a', ['b', 'c']]]
> [['d'], 'e', ['a', ['c', 'b']]]
> [['d'], 'e', [['b', 'c'], 'a']]
> [['d'], 'e', [['c', 'b'], 'a']]
> ['e', ['a', ['b', 'c']], ['d']]
> ['e', ['a', ['c', 'b']], ['d']]
> ['e', [['b', 'c'], 'a'], ['d']]
> ['e', [['c', 'b'], 'a'], ['d']]
> ['e', ['d'], ['a', ['b', 'c']]]
> ['e', ['d'], ['a', ['c', 'b']]]
> ['e', ['d'], [['b', 'c'], 'a']]
> ['e', ['d'], [['c', 'b'], 'a']]
> ```

24 permutations, as expected

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly pythonic, but I would approach it by finding permutations of the indexes, as seen here:

```
from itertools import permutations
mylist= [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
combinations = list(permutations([i for i in range(len(mylist))]))

print(combinations)

for item in combinations:
  print([mylist[item[i]] for i in range(len(mylist))])

Output:
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]
```

Comment: But there is no permutations for elements in sublists. For example there must be also something like ```[3, 1, 2] [2, 1] [1]``` and                                                           [1][2, 1, 3] [1, 2]

Comment: Define this as a function, then apply it to the sub-lists too

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using itertools?

There are explicit combination and permutation tools available

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])
>
> Return successive r length
>   permutations of elements in the iterable.
>
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the
>   iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.
>
> Permutations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the permutation tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat
>   values in each permutation.
>
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat
>   values in each combination.

Comment: It's nice that you reference the documentation... but it doesn't address the question.